# Numbers theory, combinatorics

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory

How many numbers up to $1000$ are there such that the sum of digits is divisible by $7$ and the number itself is divisible by $3$?

Comment: HINT: a number itself is divisible by 3 if and only if the sum of its digits is divisible by 3

Comment: Then the digit sum has to divisible by 21.

Comment: Then the digit sum must be 21 assuming positive integers.

Comment: hint2: max digit sum  is 27

Comment: And also [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2402018)

Answer (score 1):

Possible sums of digits that are divisible by 3: **3,6,9,12,15,21,24,27**

Possible sums that are also divisible by 7: **21**

One possible such number is 678. Six numbers can be formed using the digits 6, 7, and 8:

678, 687, 768, 786, 867, 876

But there is only one way to write those digits in increasing order: 678

So we need only to find the numbers whose digits (1): sum to 21 and (2): are in increasing order.
The other numbers will just be those numbers with the digits rearranged.

\begin{array}{|c|c|}
\hline
\text{number} & \text{number of distinct rearrangements} \\
\hline
399 & 3 \\
489 & 6 \\
579 & 6 \\
669 & 3 \\
588 & 3 \\
678 & 6 \\
777 & 1 \\
\hline
\text{TOTAL} & 28\\
\hline
\end{array}